# Detaching a browser from watin

Tags: watin

Ok, so I am misusing Watin a bit here, maybe a better tool exists (please do suggest!).

Anyway I use Watin to log in to a site, and after that I want it to leave the browser window alone...

So my question is: Is it possible to use Watin to execute some steps and then abandon the browser completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IE class has a property AutoClose. Set this to false after creating an IE instance and your Internet Explorer instance will stay open after your code has run.

HTH,
Jeroen

BTW this functionality is currently missing for FireFox. I'll add it for the next release.